# How to run terminal and execute commands on Linux (Mint 17.2, KDE, plasma) start?

Tags: terminal

Every time I sign in Mint 17.2 I open a terminal (Konsole) and go to a folder.

e.g.

```
cd /to/path
```

I found out that it's possible to run a script on system boot:

> menu --> autostart

So I created a script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd path/to/
```

but when I try to run it on konsole by

```
./my_scrypt
```

I get the error

> permission denied

What's wrong?

Also, is it the right way to open terminal --> cd path/to/ on system boot?

Comment: I'm guessing either your account is not part of sudoers or the script is running a command that requires sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should add a few lines to your user's bash files.

if you want konsole to open on login add:

```
konsole&
```

to the end of the file `~/.bash_profile`. The commands in this file are run when your user logs in.

if you want the `konsole` to `cd` to a directory when it opens add:

```
cd /to/path
```

to the end of the file `~/.bashrc`. The commands in this file are run whenever your user opens a terminal.

EDIT: to answer your direct question, to solve the permission issue perform the command `chmod 755 myscript`. You almost certainly don't have execute permissions enabled on it. This command will fail if your user does not own the file, in which case you'll have to execute the command as the file owner.